# How to convert UTC time into different time zone using angualrjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-scope

I am getting Time (hh:mm) response from api which is in UTC Time formate.As Per indian Standard Time(+5.30) I need to convert the the time.With in a controller i have Convert these things.can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use moment.js ,
suppose you are getting your request in variable say 'utctimedata'
You can use moment. js function .

```
var istCovertedData = utctimedata.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
```

You can test the same in your console if you want

```
var getcurrentdate=moment.utc("2017-01-13 20:00", "YYYY-MM-DD HH")
```

var localGetcurrentdate = getcurrentdate.local().format('YYYY-MMM-DD h:mm A');
Hope iam clear enough